# Check if var exist before unsetting in PHP?

Tags: php

With error reporting on, or even for best practice, when unsetting a variable in PHP, should you check to see if it exist first (in this case it does not always exist) and the unset it, or just unset it?

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_SESSION['signup_errors'])){
    unset($_SESSION['signup_errors']);
}

// OR

unset($_SESSION['signup_errors']);
?>
```

Comment: Cf. http://dk2.php.net/unset#77310

Comment: It is more efficient to `NOT` use `isset`. Have a look at my answer. I've done  tests to find the speed difference.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Just unset it, if it doesn't exist, nothing will be done.

Comment: I didn't know if it would throw a warning or notice

Comment: @SilentGhost I agree, it seems such a simple test, but they are asking for professional advice, and while the error log might not have any error/warning/notice unsetting an undefined var, there could have been other issues which are not logged. e.g. just calling unset means PHP raking through ALL var data because it cannot find anything, whereas using `if set` might have some better indexing scheme. (Just an example, the previous is probably cobblers and both approaches use the same data checking method).

Comment: True, and it's more efficient too. Have a look at my answer because I have tested the speed of using `isset` verses not using `isset`.

Comment: vote down - you can not unset array keys that are not defined.

Comment: That's not right, @Behnam. You cannot unset array keys of "undefined arrays". Have a look at TarranJones's answer

Comment: @jascha I said, we cannot!

Answer (score 48):

[From the PHP Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#77310):

> In regard to some confusion earlier in
>   these notes about what causes unset()
>   to trigger notices when unsetting
>   variables that don't exist....
>
> Unsetting variables that don't exist,
>   as in
>
> ```
> <?php
> unset($undefinedVariable);
> ?>
> ```
>
> does not trigger an "Undefined
>   variable" notice. But
>
> ```
> <?php
> unset($undefinedArray[$undefinedKey]);
> ?>
> ```
>
> triggers two notices, because this
>   code is for unsetting an element of an
>   array; neither $undefinedArray nor
>   $undefinedKey are themselves being
>   unset, they're merely being used to
>   locate what should be unset. After
>   all, if they did exist, you'd still
>   expect them to both be around
>   afterwards. You would NOT want your
>   entire array to disappear just because
>   you unset() one of its elements!

Comment: This needs a little more clarification. You can unset array keys that are not defined as long as the array itself exists.

Comment: @kristovaher Indeed - this doesn't address the specific scenario the OP describes at all.

Answer (score 30):

Using `unset` on an undefined variable will not cause any errors (unless the variable is the index of an array (or object) that doesn't exist).

Therefore the only thing you need to consider, is what is most efficient. It is more efficient to not test with 'isset', as my test will show.

**Test:**

```
function A()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
    {
        $defined = 1;
        unset($defined);
    }
}

function B()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
    {
        $defined = 1;
        unset($undefined);
    }
}

function C()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
    {
        $defined = 1;
        if (isset($defined))
            unset($defined);
    }
}

function D()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++)
    {
        $defined = 1;
        if (isset($undefined))
            unset($undefined);
    }
}

$time_pre = microtime(true);
A();
$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Function A time = $exec_time ";

$time_pre = microtime(true);
B();
$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Function B time = $exec_time ";

$time_pre = microtime(true);
C();
$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Function C time = $exec_time ";

$time_pre = microtime(true);
D();
$time_post = microtime(true);
$exec_time = $time_post - $time_pre;
echo "Function D time = $exec_time";
exit();
```

**Results:**

1. `Function A time = 1.0307259559631`

   - Defined without isset
2. `Function B time = 0.72514510154724`

   - Undefined without isset
3. `Function C time = 1.3804969787598`

   - Defined using isset
4. `Function D time = 0.86475610733032`

   - Undefined using isset

**Conclusion:**

It is always less efficient to use `isset`, not to mention the small amount of extra time it takes to write. It's quicker to attempt to `unset` an undefined variable than to check if it can be `unset`.

Comment: This is way better than the accepted answer! Thanks for running these tests.

Comment: You aren't testing like for like.
Memory allocation is more expensive than memory assignment, which is why A and C take longer. It's better to just think about what has to happen under the hood. php can't possibly unset something without knowing if it is set, so it must call isset internally. So, calling unset by itself will always be faster.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to unset a variable then you can just use `unset`

```
unset($any_variable); // bool, object, int, string etc
```

Checking for its existence has no benefit when trying to unset a variable.

If the variable is an array and you wish to unset an element you must make sure the *parent* exists first, this goes for object properties too.

```
unset($undefined_array['undefined_element_key']); // error - Undefined variable: undefined_array

unset($undefined_object->undefined_prop_name); // error - Undefined variable: undefined_object
```

This is easily solved by wrapping the `unset` in an `if(isset($var)){ ... }` block.

```
if(isset($undefined_array)){
    unset($undefined_array['undefined_element_key']); 
}

if(isset($undefined_object)){
    unset($undefined_object->undefined_prop_name); 
}
```

The reason we only check the variable(*parent*) is simply because we don't need to check the property/element and doing so would be a lot slower to write and compute as it would add an extra check.

```
if(isset($array)){
...
}

if(isset($object)){
...
}
```

.vs

```
$object->prop_name = null;
$array['element_key'] = null;

// This way elements/properties with the value of `null` can still be unset.

if(isset($array) && array_key_exists('element_key', $array)){
...
}

if(isset($object) && property_exists($object, 'prop_name')){
...
}

// or 

// This way elements/properties with `null` values wont be unset.

if(isset($array) && $array['element_key'])){
...
}

if(isset($object) && $object->prop_name)){
...
}
```

This goes without saying but it is also crucial that you know the `type` of the variable when getting, setting and unsetting an element or property; using the wrong syntax will throw an error.

Its the same when trying to unset the value of a multidimensional array or object. You must make sure the parent key/name exists.

```
if(isset($variable['undefined_key'])){
    unset($variable['undefined_key']['another_undefined_key']);
}

if(isset($variable->undefined_prop)){
    unset($variable->undefined_prop->another_undefined_prop);
}
```

When dealing with objects there is another thing to think about, and thats visibility.

Just because it exists doesn't mean you have permission to modify it.

Comment: Finally, a proper answer. Thank you.

Comment: A small update: In PHP 7.4/8.0 no error is thrown when you `unset` the property of a non-existing parent object. However, unsettling a key in a non-existing array in PHP8 raises not only a notice but a warning (subject to change).

Answer (score 1):

Check this link
https://3v4l.org/hPAto

The online tool shows code compatibility for different versions of PHP

According to this tool the code

```
unset($_SESSION['signup_errors']);
```

would work for PHP >=5.4.0 without giving you any notices/warnings/errors.