# How can I completly remove an object in php?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
// delete an existing app using the app path
public function deleteApp($app_path)
{
    $content = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $content = json_decode($content);

    unset($content->apps->app_path);
    dd($content);
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Which means that unset did not remove the object.

My problem, is how can I remove an entry from the `$content->apps` ?

the code used for testing, as requested

```
// --------------------------------------------- testCanDeleteApp()
public function testCanDeleteAnApp()
{
    $local_data = new LocalData;
    $app_name = $this->getRandomName();
    $app_path = 'can/you/delete/me';

    // first let's add the app and make sure it exists
    $local_data->addNewApp($app_name, $app_path);
    $this->assertTrue($local_data->isAppExists($app_path));

    // then i just delete it.
    $local_data->deleteApp($app_path);
    $this->assertFalse($local_data->isAppExists($app_path));
}
```

Comment: unset removed your `app_path` field.

Comment: try `->$app_path` syntax

Comment: Cause: `$content->apps->app_path` does *not* use the `$app_path` variable. Both "apps" and "app_path" are taken as verbatim keys.

Comment: @vp_arth no, unset does not remove app_path

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI, removes, if exists) You just haven't `app_path` field before, and this is not what you want. it's because I write my 2nd comment.

Comment: @vp_arth, yep i got this now thanks, i hope that you write the answer so i can mark it ;)

Comment: @ehime's answer is same) mark it :)

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI I believe you test fails because you are missing a slash in `$app_path = 'can/you/delete/me';` try `$app_path = '/can/you/delete/me';` I think its because you possibly concatenate your path

Comment: @ehime the problem was me forgeting to save the new content to the file, my bad, the test now is green, tnx for your support ehime :)

Comment: Awesome, glad its working mate, gl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instead

```
// delete an existing app using the app path
public function deleteApp($app_path)
{
    $content = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $content = json_decode($content);

    unset($content->apps->$app_path);
    dd($content);
}
```

Notice that there is a $ infront of the app_path `$content->apps->$app_path` where this will in turn translate to `$content->apps->the_path_you_passed_in_as_a_variable`

Comment: And where is the difference between this and OP's code?

Comment: unset is silent... isset is redundant here

Comment: @Rizier123, diff in `->$`

Comment: @vp_arth correct, I wasn't certain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374705/check-if-var-exist-before-unsetting-in-php modified my answer to reflect your input

Comment: @vp_arth The first posted answer from ehime was a exact copy of OP's code! Now he edited it...

Comment: @Rizier123 that is incorrect, please look at the answer history, there was always a `->$app_path` in my answers

Comment: @ehime i've never heard about it, but somehow it does remove the object, the only problem now is the test still failing and i don't know why ?

Comment: @OussamaELGOUMRI I'm not sure what the test is, so you will have to describe what it is and what it is doing for us to help.